# Strings as HeatMap labels

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, heatmap

I have a 40x40 matrix as my dataset and I want to assign string  variables as row and column labels to the heat map generated using MATLAB. 
I am unable to interpret the help page syntax correctly. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you share your code and the error message you get, please? That might make it easier to explain the Matlab help to you, without quoting unnecessary bits.

Comment: All I have is the matrix vector with 40x40 elements which I plotted using the HeatMap(matrix) command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The principle is always the same.** First a more generic example, and below especially for the `HeatMap` function.

---

I assume your `x` and `y` data is not the actual index vector, therefore.

```
% example data
x = linspace(-20,40,40);
y = linspace(20,100,40);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
heat = X.*Y;

% the plot
figure(1)
surf(X,Y,heat)
view(0,90)
colormap(hot)
colorbar

% the ticks
xticks = 1:numel(x);
yticks = 1:numel(y);

set(gca,'XTick',x,'XTickLabels',xticks)
set(gca,'YTick',y,'YTickLabels',xticks)
```

[image]

I personally would skip every second value and you can also move the labels, so they are located under every colored column/row, not inbetween/on the grid.

```
set(gca,'XTick',x(1:2:end)+(x(2)-x(1))/2,'XTickLabels',xticks(1:2:end))
set(gca,'YTick',y(1:2:end)+(x(2)-x(1))/2,'YTickLabels',xticks(1:2:end))
```

[image]

---

And for the `HeatMap` function. Same principle again just that you need a cell array of strings. For example I used the numbers `1 to 40` as strings. You can substitute it with your string cell array.

```
% same example data as above
xticks = 1:numel(x);
yticks = 1:numel(y);
%xticks as string cell array
xStrings = arrayfun(@num2str, xticks, 'Uniform', false);  
%yticks as string cell array
yStrings = arrayfun(@num2str, yticks, 'Uniform', false);  
HeatMap(heat,'RowLabels', yStrings, 'ColumnLabels', xStrings)
```

[image]

---

or a little more stringlike:

```
labelString = 'helloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworld';
labels = strsplit(sprintf('%c ',labelString),' ');
labels = labels(1:end-1);
HeatMap(heat,'RowLabels', fliplr(labels), 'ColumnLabels', labels)
```

[image]

Comment: I want to assign string elements as labels and I do not have the row and column vectors separate. I was trying to create the heatmap using the HeatMap function but even then assigning string element labels was difficult.